# Difference between bundle show gemname and gem list gemname

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

If I do ***gem list rack-cache*** in rails command prompt then it shows no gem with that name but if I do ***bundle show rack-cache*** then it gives me the path like ***/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-cache-1.2*** of where the gem is stored.

I didn't understood this behavior because if the gem is present in the path with the latter command then why its not showing when I gives gem list rack-cache command. 
What's the difference.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The confusion comes from the issue bundler is solving.

When you install Gems into your system-wide gem repository you end up with multiple versions of the gem once you have a couple of apps.

So for example you could end up with 3 Rails versions: 3.2.8, 3.2.6 and 3.1.0

If you do a `require rails` rubygems could use any of these versions and you'll end up with confusion if your App that was initially built against 3.1.0 isn't compatible with some change s in 3.2.8.

What bundler does is install exactly the gems that are specified in the Gemfile.lock and locks those down for the use of that app. Bundler therefore modifies the load-paths for rubygems so only the Gems in the Gemfile.lock are really available to the app.

Therefore `bundle install` is not installing gems into the system-wide gem directory but rather installs to a different path for each project. That's why you see the gem in a bundler directory and not system wide.
If you install `rack-cache` through `gem install` you'll also see it in `gem list`.

Comment: Oh thanx. The point is bundle install is having an application scope whereas the gem install is having a system wide scope. Confusion cleared.

Answer (score 2):

There is a small difference between **`bundle show`** and **`gem list`**

**`bundle show`** will list all the gems which are installed in your current application[you can see them in Gemfile.lock file],where as **`gem list`** will list all the gems installed under any `gemset` which is set to be using.

**`bundle show gem_name`** will give path where it is.
**`gem list gem_name`** will give same gem_name with all versions installed into your local gems or gemset.

Answer (score 2):

bundle show :

Shows all gems that are part of the bundle, or the path to a given gem

$ bundle show [GEM] [--paths]

When in development mode on your mac, the gems still get installed in the default gem path, whereas in production mode, they get installed in a folder specific to your project. Try doing a bundle show rails on each machine and you'll see what I mean.

When you run gem list it looks in the main gem folder, and since your production gems are sitting in a project-specific folder, the global gem command doesn't know to look there. So you will need to do a bundle exec to run any of those project-specific gemscommands on the server. For my purposes, I created a be alias to bundle exec. Also, to list your project's gems, you can do bundle list.

See http://gembundler.com/rationale.html#deploying-your-application for the rationale behind this